# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, jwt

every time I try to run my program using `python manage.py runserver` the same error comes up. I have already added my Django app in my settings.py. this error first came up after starting my Django project and installing my Django app. The error:

```
> Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\jwt-believe-0.0.1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\jwt-believe-0.0.1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 115, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\jwt-believe-0.0.1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\jwt-believe-0.0.1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\jwt-believe-0.0.1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\jwt-believe-0.0.1\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\jwt-believe-0.0.1\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\jwt-believe-0.0.1\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'
```

Here are my installed apps:

> 

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'base.apps.BaseConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

This is my apps.py :

> 

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class BaseConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'base'
```

I restarted the project many times using different methods, I tried to switch databases, and even uninstalled Django and reinstalled it but all of this was to no avail as this issue kept on coming up over and over again.

Comment: what "modules" do you have installed?  Maybe you forgot to "activate" your Python virtual environment?

Comment: the virtual environment is activated and only Django is installed

Comment: Just add base instead of base.apps.BaseConfig

Comment: I tried that, but it shows the same error

Comment: maybe my settings.py cant access my base app, I don't know I am new to this.